# Cordova: firebase disconnected after login

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using cordova/phonegap with angularjs+firebase, after creating the account firebase, it automatically disconnect

intelxdk.config.android.app.xml

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:intelxdk="http://xdk.intel.com/ns/v1" id="com.intel.appx.xwalk16" version="0.3.1" android-versionCode="1">
    <intelxdk:version value="1.0"/>
    <intelxdk:cordova-cli version="5.4.1"/>
    <name>AP Debug x16</name>
    <description>Universal init code for Intel XDK and Cordova device ready detection, as well as within browser.</description>
    <author>Intel XDK</author>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="*.firebaseio.com"/>
    <allow-intent href="auth.firebase.com"/>
    <allow-navigation href="*"/>
    <intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="StatusBar" intelxdk:value="cordova-plugin-statusbar" intelxdk:version="2.1.0" intelxdk:checksum="858cc583" intelxdk:type="file"/>
    <intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="Device" intelxdk:value="cordova-plugin-device" intelxdk:version="1.1.1" intelxdk:checksum="927290ca" intelxdk:type="file"/>
    <intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="Splashscreen" intelxdk:value="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" intelxdk:version="3.2.0" intelxdk:checksum="452a4659" intelxdk:type="file"/>
    <intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="BarcodeScanner" intelxdk:value="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" intelxdk:version="4.1.0" intelxdk:checksum="980170d7" intelxdk:type="file"/>
    <intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="Whitelist" intelxdk:value="cordova-plugin-whitelist" intelxdk:version="1.2.3-dev" intelxdk:checksum="e2e4b8f1" intelxdk:type="file"/>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="21"/>
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
    <preference name="android-signed" value="true"/>
    <intelxdk:crosswalk version="16"/>
```

Create function

```
    var ref = new Firebase("https://foobar.firebaseio.com");
    var fireAcc = $firebaseAuth(ref);
    function createFirebaseAcc(data){
        fireAcc.$createUser(data).then(function(authData) {
            console.log(authData);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
```

[The user was created in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFmAv.png).

Comment: What do you mean with it disconnects? [Creating an account will not log that new account in.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/password.html)

Comment: after creating the account it automatically disconnects the firebase connection, then I get an error. if I try to log in to account, it disconnects then